# Convert table with select fields to js array

Tags: javascript

```js
function extractTable() {

    var csvTable = document.querySelector("#csv_table");
    var newTableObj = [];
    var tableRows = [].reduce.call(csvTable.rows, function(res, row) { 
              
        res[row.cells[0].textContent] = row.cells[1].textContent;
        return res
      
    }, {});
    delete tableRows['Column value']; // Removes the header row

    // Create an object
    newTableObj.push(tableRows);
    console.log(newTableObj);

    // Create a JSON
    let jsonTable = JSON.stringify(tableRows, null, 2);
    console.log(jsonTable);
};
```

```html
<table id="csv_table" class="sms_table">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Column value</th>
   <th>Field</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>Name</td>
   <td>
    <select id="select_path" class="field_select">
     <option selected="selected" value="">Please assign a Field</option>
     <option value="a">A</option>
     <option value="b">B</option>
    </select>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Prefix</td>
   <td>
    <select id="select_path" class="field_select">
     <option selected="selected" value="">Please assign a Field</option>
     <option value="a">A</option>
     <option value="b">B</option>
    </select>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>First</td>
   <td>
    <select id="select_path" class="field_select">
     <option selected="selected" value="">Please assign a Field</option>
     <option value="a">A</option>
     <option value="b">B</option>
    </select>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Last</td>
   <td>
    <select id="select_path" class="field_select">
     <option selected="selected" value="">Please assign a Field</option>
     <option value="a">A</option>
     <option value="b">B</option>
    </select>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<button id="extractTable" onclick="extractTable()">Extract table</button>
```

I have a simple two column table which is generated based upon the results of a parsed CSV file. The left column contains all of the values extracted, and the right column are a series of dropdowns which people can select a value.

I have some code which runs through the rows and extracts the values, which then I can drop into a multidimensional array or JSON.

I would like to be able to store these for use elsewhere but seem completely unable to extract the values of the dropdown field. Can anyone please help me?

My HTML table is something like this:

```
<table id="csv_table" class="sms_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column value</th>
            <th>Field</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>
                <select id="select_path" class="field_select">
                    <option selected="selected" value="">Please assign a Field</option>
                    <option value="a">A</option>
                    <option value="b">B</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Prefix</td>
           <td>
                <select id="select_path" class="field_select">
                    <option selected="selected" value="">Please assign a Field</option>
                    <option value="a">A</option>
                    <option value="b">B</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<button id="extractTable" onclick="extractTable()">Extract table</button>
```

My Js is:

```
function extractTable() {
    var csvTable = document.querySelector("#csv_table");
    var newTableObj = [];
    var tableRows = [].reduce.call(csvTable.rows, function(res, row) {           
        res[row.cells[0].textContent] = row.cells[1].textContent;
        return res
    }, {});
    delete tableRows['Column value']; // Removes the header row

    // Create an object
    newTableObj.push(tableRows);
    console.log(newTableObj);

    // Create a JSON
    let jsonTable = JSON.stringify(tableRows, null, 2);
    console.log(jsonTable);
};
```

My example codepen is here: https://codepen.io/AllenT871/pen/XoazJz?editors=1011#

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting all the table you could get only the selectors using `document.getElementsByClassName` o `document.getElementsByTagName`

Then you can iterate (but its NOT an iterable you cannot use `map` or `reduce`) and get the selected value of every select.

I hope it helps

All code:

```
function extractTable() {
    var tableItems = document.getElementsByClassName("field_select");
    var tableRows = [];       

    for(var i = 0; i<tableItems.length; i++){
      var e = tableItems[i]
      var option = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
      console.log(option)
      tableRows.push(option);
    }

    // Create a JSON
    let jsonTable = JSON.stringify(tableRows, null, 2);
    console.log(jsonTable);
};
```

Comment: Thank you Luby, that was really helpful. I managed to work with your solution and output the whole table now: https://codepen.io/AllenT871/pen/EGvEqM?editors=1011